# Trouble with UpSet(Delayed) and IgnoringInactive

Tags: pattern-matching, hold, assignment

I'm having problems setting an upvalue for a symbol that is supposed to ignore `Inactive`:

```
IgnoringInactive[f[g[x]]] ^:= match;
```

Then for some reason, this fails to match:

```
f[Inactive[g][x]]
```

> [image]

I also tried `TagSet`, as in `g /: IgnoringInactive[f[g[x]]] := match` but that didn't work either.

What is the intended way to assign a rule to `g` while ignoring possible `Inactive` wrapper around `g`?

Comment: Since `g` is inactive, no rules associated with it are used. What about tag set for `f`?

Comment: It does set an upvalue, but perhaps @Kuba is saying that the upvalue is not invoked, so you don't get the result of `f[Inactive[g][x]] /. UpValues[g]`, which yields `match`. I think it's worth reporting to WRI. Either you should get the result or the attempt to set the upvalue should give an error. Or at worst, there could be this sort of example added to the possible issues section of the docs for `IgnoringInactive`.

Comment: To add my take on Kuba's comment: The upvalue is not invoked because `g` is too deep in the expression `f[Inactive[g][x]]`. When reaching `g`, the evaluator looks for upvalue matching `Inactive[g]`, of which there isn't one. So it goes on its merry way. It wasn't redesigned to go up one more level in the case when it gets `Inactive[symbol]` to see if there are `IgnoringInactive` upvalue rules that match. But that's just guess.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think it is correct though it could be confusing at first. My opinion is that example is not a use case for `IgnoringInactive`.  I would arguee with error on set upvalue because `Inactive[f][g[x]]` will be matched well.

Comment: @MichaelE2 about your second comment, I didn't thought about this and it makes more sense. I should probably delete my previous comments.